# 2D grids blocks on opencl

Tags: opencl

I am trying to use 2d grids and blocks on opencl. On cuda that was easy but on OpenCl it is so confusing. I tried to use 2x2 grid and each block have 4x4 threads, :

```
size_t **global_item_size2 = malloc (2 * sizeof(size_t *) + (2 * (2 * sizeof(size_t))));
size_t **local_item_size2 = malloc (4 * sizeof(size_t *) + (4 * (4 * sizeof(size_t))));
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, myKernel, 2, NULL, (size_t*)&*global_item_size2, (size_t*)&*local_item_size2, 0, NULL, &event);
```

it compiles but when I am trying to run I am getting

Error @ clEnqueueNDRangeKernel: CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE

How can I use 2d blocks and 2d grids on OpenCl?

Comment: global_item_size2 should be an array which must have only two values for your problem.  First value is size of X-dimension and the second is Y-dimension size. So you malloc for only 2 elements and assign "4" and "4" to have a 4x4 work area for enqueue command. Same goes for local too.(like 2 and 2 for 2-element aray) Actual data array info is used/read/written by another command. Also sizeof(size_t *) is wrong here. You use that for read/write buffer operations and that will be sizeof(cl_float) or similar.

Comment: So, it expects two numbers(x,y dimension sizes) in the first two elements of your arrays but finds garbage. just put a "new size_t[]{4,4}" in there to check if it works, then you can tidy the code to clean the 2-element leak.

Comment: You set global to 2x2 and local to 4x4, that can't be. Global is the TOTAL amount of threads, so it should be 8x8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it like this: **(UPDATED in pure C)**

```
//Create the size holders
size_t * global = (size_t*) malloc(sizeof(size_t)*2);
size_t * local = (size_t*) malloc(sizeof(size_t)*2);

//Set the size
global[0] = 8; global[1] = 8;
local [0] = 4; local [1] = 4;

//Run
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, myKernel, 2, NULL, global, local, 0, NULL, &event);

//Clean the size holders
free(global);
free(local);
```

In addition, your concepts are wrong:

- The number of TOTAL work-items is the **global** size
- The **global** size is subdivided in work-groups for processing, each made of the **local** size

So it should be 8x8 global, 4x4 local, giving it 2x2 work-groups.

> 8x8(global) = 4x4(local) * 2x2(groups)

Comment: I can't use `new` there is a compilation error, I suppose that I have to use malloc. Thank you for your help

Comment: Ups, yes if you are PURE C then you have to use malloc. I update the example with C.